# How do I tell the `date` command to only show the time?

Tags: command-line

I am trying to display only the current time using "date", not all that information Day, Month, Year etc.. , only the current time.

i.e.:

13:45 or 1:45pm

Any ideas?

Comment: This site works best when there's one question per post, please ask your question about time since reboot as a new one, thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
date +%R
```

will show you the 24 hour time, and

```
date +%r
```

will show you the time in 12 hour format. `date +%H:%I` also works.

Check out the "Conversion Specifications" in [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/date.1posix.html) for more variables to pick and choose.

Comment: Do I still have to repost the other question or an OP will repost it for me ?

Comment: Go ahead and post it!

Comment: worth saying that while `%R` is like `%H:%M`, `%r` is like `%I:%M:%S`. So the 12h version of `%R` is `%I:%M%p`. `%H:%I` instead looks wrong to me (it gives you hour in 24h and hour in 12h).

Comment: `date +%T` in case you want seconds as well

Answer (score 4):

Current time 24h format:

```
date +%R
```

Current time 12h format with AM/PM:

```
date +%I:%M%p
```

Answer (score 4):

```
date +%H:%M
```

for 13:45

```
date +%H:%M #(if you don't write these : it is shown as for exmp. 0145)
```

for 01:45

```
"uptime"
```

will tell how long the system has been running (along with other information)
check man entry for uptime

Comment: It is not 1:45 it is 01:45, I edited post

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
date +%T
```

for nanoseconds use this:

```
date +%T.%N
```

Example outputs:

```bash
$ date +%T
19:23:34
$ date +%T.%N
19:23:38.780062589
```

Answer (score 0):

`last` displays info about recent logins. See http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_last.htm for more info about it. I think it can show shutdowns too. For the time try `date +%r`. See http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_date.htm for more info on date.

Comment: I've asked the OP to repost that as a new question, when he does please post this there and then remove it from here, thanks!

Comment: @JorgeCastro thanks. Didn't know about that. I am newbie in linux, and I am trying to learn it and this seems the only place where I can do this.

Comment: No worries, keep on rocking!

Comment: Will do... Awaiting new question...

Comment: @JamesCrawshaw I've posted new question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/335592/how-to-display-time-elapsed-since-last-system-boot-using-uptime/335598?noredirect=1#335598