# How to display time elapsed since last system boot using "uptime"?

Tags: command-line

I want to display the time elapsed since last system boot using `uptime`, but I don't want it to display all that info. I just want to know how many hours passed since last system boot (i.e. : 18:17:59)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To get the time elapsed since last system boot in `hh:mm:ss` format, you can use:

```
awk '{print int($1/3600)":"int(($1%3600)/60)":"int($1%60)}' /proc/uptime
```

`/proc/uptime` pseudo-file contains two numbers:

- The first number is how long the system has been up in seconds.
- The second number is how much of that time the machine has spent idle in seconds.

So, using `awk` you can take firs number and convert it in `hh:mm:ss` format.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the second number is the time spent idle by all CPUs and so it can be much bigger than the actual uptime. For an n-CPU system, the second number can *approach* n times the actual uptime which is represented by the first number. For example, an embedded platform I'm running that has 2 CPUs currently shows "6032.31 11574.35" as the contents of `/proc/uptime`

Answer (score 23):

To get uptime in seconds:

```
awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime
```

To get uptime in minutes:

```
 echo $(awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime) / 60 | bc
```

To get uptime in hours:

```
 echo $(awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime) / 3600 | bc
```

To get x digits of precision you can add scale=x, e.g. for x=2

```
echo "scale=2; $(awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime) / 3600" | bc
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
uptime | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

In fact, it prints the third word of the line produced by `uptime`.

Comment: It works. But it doesn't seems the right way to do it. What if the third word isn't the time, for example my third word is "4" , because my machine is running for 4 days. This is what I get: "02:00:39 up 4 days, 12:54, 2 users, load average: 0.03. 0.06, 0.06" .

Comment: Oh :D I didn’t know about the time more than 1 day!

Comment: It ok :d now you have some answers to this?

Comment: No, sorry. `uptime` seems to have no options but I couldn’t find anything on the net either.

Answer (score 3):

A trivial modification to show days:

```
awk '{print int($1/86400)"days "int($1%86400/3600)":"int(($1%3600)/60)":"int($1%60)}' /proc/uptime
```

Answer (score 3):

figured I'd add mine to the collection since there's nothing similar...
tried to be more efficient with mine:

```sh
awk '{m=$1/60; h=m/60; printf "%sd %sh %sm %ss", int(h/24), int(h%24), int(m%60), int($1%60) }' /proc/uptime
```

result:
`42d 17h 23m 55s`

EDIT:
since I realized I didn't *quite* answer the original question, here's a revision specifically for that:

```sh
awk '{m=$1/60; h=m/60; printf "%s:%s:%s", int(h%24), int(m%60), int($1%60) }' /proc/uptime
```

result:
`17:23:55`

Comment: Nice one, thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

This will format your output as 2 zero padding:

```
awk '{printf("%02d:%02d:%02d",int($1/3600),int($1/3600/60),int($1%60))}' /proc/uptime
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @realmoonstruck answer:

You could do this solely in awk which saves you one pipe and the subsequent call of `bc`.

To get the uptime in minutes:

```bsh
awk '{print int($1)/60}' /proc/uptime
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple metrics, I sometimes just want an INT of the hours:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -eux
upsince=$(date +%s -d "$(uptime -s)");
now=$(date +%s);
DIFF=$((now-upsince));
scale=2;

echo $((DIFF / 3600)))
```

NOTE: You could '+ 1' to round up to the nearest full hour

Answer (score 0):

A further trivial modification for layout:

```
UPTIME_STR=$(awk '{print int($1/86400)"d "int($1%86400/3600)"h "int(($1%3600)/60)"m "int($1%60)"s"}' /proc/uptime)
echo "['$(date)'] Device Uptime:" $UPTIME_STR
```

Example Output:

> ['Mon Jan 17 22:41:32 SAST 2022'] Device Uptime: 0d 0h 10m 58s

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{printf( "%04d:%02d:%02d:%02d\n",int($1/86400) , int(($1%86400)/3600) , int(($1%3600)/60) , int($1%60)  )}'  /proc/uptime;
```

Format [dddd:hh:mm:ss] 
Sample: 0122:05:14:03