# Is there any command to show how much time your ubuntu is on?

Tags: command-line, time

is there any command which tells you, how much times you turn on your Ubuntu? For example in 8 AM you turn on ubuntu and at 10 AM you write that command and the result is two hours?

Comment: Related: [How to display time elapsed since last system boot using “uptime”?](http://askubuntu.com/q/335592/147044)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give a try to `uptime` command,

```
$ uptime -s
2014-06-17 09:36:38
```

OR

```
$ uptime -p
up 10 hours, 12 minutes
```

From `uptime --help`

```
-p, --pretty   show uptime in pretty format

-s, --since    system up since
```

From `man uptime`,

```
   uptime gives a one line display of the following information.  The cur‐
   rent time, how long the system has been running,  how  many  users  are
   currently  logged  on,  and the system load averages for the past 1, 5,
   and 15 minutes.
```

Comment: The `-p` and `-s` options seem to be non-standard, they don't exist on my Debian 7.5 server.

Comment: @nyuszika7h we are not talking about debian.

Comment: @nyuszika7h You do realize this is the _Ubuntu_ site, right? That said, I think it warrants at least a footnote mention.

Comment: @BlacklightShining Yes. I had a friend test on his Xubuntu VM, and those options don't exist there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `uptime` if you just want to know it from a Terminal.
Or you could use a systemmonitor like `conky` to display it permanently on the desktop.